# How do I identify the important specs for this part?

Tags: sensor, identification, components

How do I figure out the relevant specs needed to order this chip?

I found a really cool and insanely expensive ski waxing iron at the dump and am pretty sure I can fix it if I can figure out the relevant specs for this triac sense gate!

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/thyristors-triacs/300?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEIBU4EYwFoBsAGLIC6AvkA

[image]

** Update **
The iron works! Dissembling it jostled a loose connection back into place and the chip wasn't needed after all.

To answer my own question of how to decipher specs off a mystery chip, the aha moment was finding this schematic in the data sheet (intuitively called *ordering information*  though in my defence the chip had an old code on it that didn't exactly match):

[image]

It seems like a simple thing to say "just make sure the specs match" but there are so many values it's tricky as beginner to figure out which ones don't have to match exactly.

I don't need to order the part anymore but I think I figured out which triac I would have needed to order and am curious if I got it right!

**T1235H-6T** is compatible with **BTB12-6CWG**

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a3/76/a9/5d/d0/3d/41/4d/CD00161295.pdf/files/CD00161295.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161295.pdf

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/t1250.pdf

Comment: This is https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/thyristors-scr-and-ac-switches/triacs/standard-and-snubberless-triacs/btb12.html by st microelectronics.

Comment: This is 12A snubberless logic level and standard Triacs.

Comment: CWG part see  datasheet of BTB12 page 11.  CW=35 mA Snubberless G = D2PAK

Comment: *Can I use any* - check parameters before use. You can use if  parameters success.You can also choose triacs from another manufacturer.

Comment: The CW is important because that identifies the sensitivity of the gate, so a different part may not work properly.  Be aware though that the codes printed on the device often aren’t the same as the device part number - sometimes they include a date code and a part of the part number, sometimes they bear no relation at all.  In this case it more or less matches though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is likely to attract unsympathetic attention because it’s a ‘where to buy’ question.  However, Digikey sells this device, it appears to be made by On Semiconductor and its a BTB12-600 triac.  Be sure to choose the correct package, this one is a TO-220.

Comment: Questions asking where to buy are off-topic for a reason, perhaps you should recognize that.

Comment: One moment while I educate myself...

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Right then... shopping questions are deprecated because any information that the answers provide is likely to be specific to geographic locality and other factors and may well become obsolete quickly, so the answers are less likely to be useful to a wide audience.  However, asking for help in identifying the component is (as far as I can see) acceptable.  I invite the OP to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Frog thanks for your thoughts! First time using this forum--didn't realize I was off topic and reframed my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  It looks like the rubber has hit the road :-)

Comment: @Frog Road? Where, where?

Comment: @Russell McMahon it’s a small celebration of the OP’s first foray into this group, which seems to be making a little progress now that the formalities have been addressed :-)